# nginx ustream list server weight

Tags: nginx

OK, so here is my Conf:

```
upstream sun {
    server 127.0.0.1:11211;
}

upstream moon {
    server 127.0.0.2:11211;
}

upstream_list universe sun moon;
.... more lines ...
location = /memc {
        internal;

        set $memc_key $query_string;
        set_hashed_upstream $backend universe $memc_key;
        set $memc_exptime 86400; # in seconds
        memc_pass $backend;
    }
```

The question is, how do I:

1. Assign Weight to an upstream? I know that I can assign weight's in upstream server, but how do I do it for an Upstream?
2. Assign max_fails and fail_timeout???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the purpose of a **set_hashed_upstream** is to make sure that specific **$memc_key** will hit the specific backend all the time - each object will be cached only once, on it's own server. That means you probably don't want to make them weighted: you want specific key to always hit the same backend - otherwise multiple backends will have to hold copies of the same object.

That said, if it's not an issue and you still want to distribute evenly - you will be better of using single upstream with multiple server with ip_hash or round robin. Potentially, in the long run it would probably mean that ALL of your objects are cached on EACH of the servers.

Ok, if you want to go further there is a slightly convoluted way to take control over the hash distribution using your own code. You could write a hash function which, while ensuring that specific hash will hit the same server all the time, will create weighted distribution of hashes, making sure some servers are hit more than others. Here how to integrate it into nginx config:

*DISCLAIMER: I didn't try it myself.*

1. Set up the **max_fails** and **fail_timeout** ( but not the weight ) parameters separately for each server in a corresponding upstream, i.e:

   ```
    upstream sun {
        server 127.0.0.1:11211 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=10;
    }
   ```
2. Configure HttpLuaModule

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule

1. Configure the backend selection using lua script.

   ```
   location = /memc {
           internal;

           set $memc_key $query_string;
           set $memc_exptime 86400; # in seconds
           set $upstream_list="sun moon"
           set $upstream_weights="5 10"
           set_by_lua_file $backend "conf/hash.lua" $memc_key $upstream_list $upstream_wieghts;
           memc_pass $backend;
   }
   ```
2. You could, then, write a hash function, which will return an appropriate backend. You will have to define an algorithm to take weights into an account (like, for example, return one backend 5 times more often then the other). You can then access the arguments using ngx.arg[i].

Simple example to base the algorithm upon:

- suppose memc_key is between 1 and 10,
- if it's between 1 and 6 included - return first server (weight 6)
- if it's between 7 and 10 included - return second server (weight 4)

(This is just to give you a general idea)

This should give you exactly what you want.

Source of an inspiration:

http://agentzh.org/misc/slides/nginx-state-of-the-art/#69